# Function to add to a counter throws local variable error

Tags: python, function, global-variables, counter, python-3.6

I am trying to make a function that adds to a simple variable counter.

```
counter = 0
```

If I just do it like this, I get the following error:

```
 def counter_adder(rank):
      if rank < 5:
           counter = counter + 1
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'in_in' referenced before assignment

I can make it work by adding a `global` variable within the function:

```
 def counter_adder(rank):
      global counter
      if rank < 5:
           counter = counter + 1
```

However, I've heard this is bad (why?) and wanted to know if there was a better way to do this?

Comment: It's not that using the `global` statement is bad. What's bad is using global variables.

Comment: Does that mean the way I am doing this is OK?

Comment: Yes and no. It might be better not to have a global `counter` variable, but that's impossible to say without any context.

Comment: In general, global variables should be evaded where possible. The reason for that is, that it becomes hard to track which function changes the value at which time. Use a class or function attribute where possible or pass and return the counter.

Comment: You already pass in `rank` as an argument to your function. Why not pass in `counter` as well?

Comment: You should either pass and return `counter` or have `adder` be a method of a `Counter` class.

Comment: So, something like this: `def counter_adder(rank, counter=0):` Would that work? I just want to make sure that I can still access counter outside of the function and that every time it's run, it adds the +1 appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out recently, that you can attach attributes to functions. This would be the exact use-case for something like that.

```
def counter_adder(rank):
  if rank < 5:
    counter_adder.counter+=1

counter_adder.counter = 0

counter_adder(5)

print(counter_adder.counter)
```